# html button get and enter the mail, a letter is sent to the specified e-mail

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I make this in such a way that when I press enter the mail and press the button, a letter is sent to the specified e-mail?

```
<div class="home-get">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your work email…" class="text-input">
  <div class="button-home">
    <a class="button" href="#">Get a demo</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is impossible to do with just html, since you will need to use a web server to actually send the email. In nodejs, I am rather certain you can use [node-mailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).